# Writing concurrent JUnit for Non-Concurrent Program

Tags: java, spring, junit, concurrency, junit5

We have a `non-concurrent` java snippet to generate jwt token and now need to write `JUnit` for the same.

There are few queries about this :

1. Is it valid to write `concurrent junit` for `non-concurrent code`?
2. If yes, what I should try to `JUnit` in that except the normal flow? as there is not `shared/mutable` property.

Comment: I assume you’re talking about parallel JUnit tests not concurrent ones. That said your question is unclear to me, especially why do you think parallelising (if my assumption above is correct) will improve your testing? It’s hard to imagine jwt creating code that is so computation heavy that parallelisation is necessary. Can you clarify?

Comment: @johanneslink No, I want this code to run concurrently to check it's behaviour in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @MehrajMalik If you say there is no "state" associated with your code , and still want to test that piece of code when there are parallel requests JUnit may not be the right approach , you may probably have to consider tools like gatling(https://gatling.io/) , it is extensible
You can write gradle tasks to trigger tests that target your piece of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is probably - 'thread safety'.

**if you need to prove the code works in a multi-threaded scenario**

1. yes it should be tested
2. if the code (class / object) is 'stateless' - the tests should be simpler -validate that output is only input or non-shared time/nonce based.

(you haven't shared code - so this is a general answer.
In your case if jwt token is being created - implies that - concurrent invocation will returns different token values. hence the assertions should confirm the same. )